# catchError with throwError fails jasmine test with Uncaught [object Object] thrown message

Tags: angular, unit-testing, error-handling, jasmine, rxjs

I'm creating a custom error handler for my angular app.

I have this component calling a service method, which does a http request and returns an observable. On that returned observable, I added a pipe with a **map** operator (to do some stuff in case of success), and **catchError** handling the error re-throwing it in the end, and finally the **subscribe()** empty, so my custom error handler get the error and log it.

The app is working fine, the error handling is working as expected. My problem is with the test I wrote for that component. In the first time it runs ok, but after any change in the file the test runs fail with the message:

```
    Chrome 73.0.3683 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
      {
        "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown",
        "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown"
      }
```

**<edit-1>**

Chrome console output:

[image]

**</edit-1>**

And after that the test does not run again and only the message 
`WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/` is displayed.

I know the issue is because of the `catchError` + `throwError`. When I add `.subscribe(() => {}, (err) => {});` test runs fine, but the custom error handling doesn't get the error anymore.

Here's the link with the code https://gist.github.com/emilio2hd/75a54286e45ca7def85f4a71967ade90

I'm not sure if that kind of strategy is correct or not, but I would like not have to inject and call a sort of error handling service or function for every subscribe.

Thank you anyway!

Comment: I can see that `SomeGenericComponent.onDoStuff` is asynchronous, it subscribes to the observable that `myGenericService.doStuff` returns.

Your test needs to know when the async code has completed.


Maybe you are missing async handling in your tests and

Comment: You may need to update your code to subscribe to onDoStuff() from the outside so you can know (from the outside) when your code is done.

I posted code example as comment to your gist.

Comment: Hi @RicardoFornes ! Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, didn't work.
As I have a **throwError** inside of my **catchError**, the first function of the subscribe would never be called.